# CSS File different when copied

Tags: html, css

I am trying to adapt the [CSS file found here](http://dreamhost.com/wp-content/themes/dreamhost/style.css).

When I include it on my website using the following code in an `.html` document:

```
<link media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dreamhost.com/wp-content/themes/dreamhost/style.css" />
```

it appears like so:

[image: Working]

Notice how it starts blue and fades to white.

However if I copy the contents of that `.css` to a new file and change the `href="mystyle.css"`, it becomes solid light blue.  It doesn't fade into white or anything:

[image: Not working]

I don't know anything about CSS, so I was going to use this to learn via small modifications.  However I cannot figure out why I don't get the same result via copy/paste of the code into a file.

Anyone know what might be going wrong here?!?

Comment: Is that happening in all browsers or just IE?  some css gradient generators require additional style rules to be applied when doing certain IE gradients.

Comment: It was happening in Firefox and IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the CSS file you have:

```
background:#bfd6ee url(images/bg-body.gif) repeat-x;
```

It's attempting to find the file `images/bg-body.gif`, but if it can't find that file, the solid background of `#bfd6ee` (a blue-ish color) shows instead.  You'll want to copy over `images/bg-body.gif` into the relative `images` directory in order to get the gradient look.

Also, note that this CSS file has references to several *other* files as well: external.png, bg-soft-light.png, bg-input.gif, etc.  If you're hoping to use other styles from this stylesheet, you might run into similar problems.  Sometimes themes have a single ZIP file with all the dependencies that you can just unzip onto your web server and everything just works.  However, learning a few CSS basics would help you out as well.

Comment: Ahhh yess thank you.  I couldn't figure this out for the life of me.  I cannot accept the answer for another few minutes, but I will.  Thanks! :D

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma - In style.css, line 69.  The `background` style of the `body` tag refers to that specific file.  The CSS also refers to a bunch of other files as well, so this might be the first of many problems.  Perhaps there's a ZIP file that contains the entire theme you can download?

Comment: I'll just ctrl+f to find all gifs needed and download them.  After a while I will likely change all of them.  I didn't expect so many external files for a simple example .css haha.  I figured it would be a self-contained color style with some .css magic.

Comment: @MrHappyAsthma - Yea, there are some pure CSS ways to get a gradient effect like that, but they're not guaranteed to work on every browser.  What `bg-body.gif` probably is, is a *really tall* one pixel wide image.  `repeat-x` makes the browser repeat the image along the x axis over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

What most likely happened is... you copied the CSS file which was including the image it has for the gradient which defaulted (if not found or could not display) to the blue you show in your 2nd example.

When you copied the css file but did not include the image... it defaulted to the blue.

Go back to that source and find the CSS image it was referencing and add it as well, make sure pathing and etc. is correct

```
body {
    color:#333;
    font:13px "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    min-width:1002px;
    background:#bfd6ee url(images/bg-body.gif) repeat-x;
}
```

So get the image: `images/bg-body.gif`  from the source and add it to your project